# How to bulk-extract objects from swf (Adobe Flash) files with swfextract?

Tags: extract, swf, format-conversion

`swftools` are a unique set of tools but lack some user friendliness. They can't even  iterate over provided objects:

> Only one file allowed. You supplied at least two.

```
$ swfextract file.swf -i 1,2
warning! You should use the -P when extracting multiple objects

$ ls
file.swf  output.swf

$ swfextract file.swf -i 1,2 -P

$ ls
file.swf  output.swf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a bash script to automate it:

```
#!/bin/bash
find_ext=".swf"
out_ext=".jpg"

[ "$1" == "" ] && echo "Add type arguments from swfextract: -j -p -f -F -m -i" && exit 1 

for arg in $@; do
    for file in `find . -name "*$find_ext"`; do 
    ids="`swfextract $file | grep "\[$arg\]" | sed 's#^.*ID(s) ##g' |  sed 's#, # #g'`"
        for id in $ids; do
            swfextract "$file" $arg $id -o "${file}_${id}${out_ext}"
        done
    done
done
```

Don't forget to check the `*_ext` variables.
Feel free to improve the script by adding extensions automatically.

Comment: I know this is very old, but I have a number of swf files each with a number of photos in them.  I'm barely bash competent, so your code above is greek to me.  I just created a bash script and put it in the folder with the swf files and when I run it is just spits out: Add type arguments from swfextract: -j -p -f -F -m -i

A.  Will the script above run through each swf and export each JPG?
B.  What am I doing wrong?  I don't understand what "Add type arguments from swfextract" means or where to add them even if I did.

Comment: C.  Also don't understand what you mean by "Don't forget to check the *_ext variables?

Comment: Try running this script with `-j` as the first argument, it's needed for catching IDs of objects (used in the line with `grep`). This way it should extract all JPEGs, meaning of other options should be on http://www.swftools.org/swfextract.html Maybe `-p` will work too and I'm not sure about others.

Comment: Thanks so much for answering!  Greatness!  I am not following how I add in arguments?  Like this?  

find_ext=".swf"
out_ext=".jpg"
$arg = "-P"

Comment: No, not in the script itself, when launching it, add the argument after its' name, something like this: `./bulk_swfextract.sh -j` where `bulk_swfextract.sh` is the filename of the script.

Comment: Ahhhh.  Totally got it.  The combo of -p and -j extracted a ton of jpgs from a ton of swf files.  Thanks so much!!!!

Answer (score 3):

**Use this one-liner**

```
swfextract --outputformat "extract_%06d.%s" -a 1- file.swf
```

If you want to extract to a dir `content`, make that dir first:

```
mkdir content
swfextract --outputformat "content/extract_%06d.%s" -a 1- file.swf
```

Works fine.

See the [docs](http://wiki.swftools.org/wiki/Swfextract).

Comment: It does what it say it does. Extract all objects TO a folder `content`.